# Registering Google Apps Script Web App with Tiny Cloud

Tags: html, google-apps-script, tinymce

As the name states, I am trying to register my company's Google Apps Script Web App with Tiny Cloud to get the error: "This Domain is not registered with Tiny Cloud. Please review your approved domains." I've tried submitting my web apps ACTUAL URL, but it keeps defaulting to "script.google.com", which is obviously not the URL, and doesn't work. Could it be because it's being hosted through my company, and only people can internally use the web app?

I'm still able to use Tiny MCE, the text editor, but these errors won't stop appearing and I'm not sure as to why that's the case.

This is my script API tag to actually get everything from Tiny MCE:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/<MY-API-KEY>/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js"
    referrerpolicy="origin">
</script>
```

I can provide more details as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What value is being passed as the `Referer` header with the request to load the Tiny Cloud script?

The `Referer` is what is used to validate the domain.

Comment: After following this guide [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/domain-registered-with-tiny-cloud-referer/), and finding what my `Referer` actually was, it was different from my URL, so posting that as my domain in Tiny Cloud corrected the issue. Thank you for bringing that to my attention